# Copy and past test cases into Office - or plugin

Tags: testing, junit, ms-office

I have an Eclipse project with several test cases (400 at least) and I need to copy and past the results into Office (Word or Excel) because I need to report these into a table.

What is the best way to do this? Because I don't see alternative to write them one by one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asking to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If you generate an HTML report, you could then use docx4j's XHTML import to convert that to a docx.  Or you could try opening the HTML report directly in Word (then "Save As" docx if necessary).